# Slicing a list using a variable, in Python

Tags: python, list, slice

Given a list

```
a = range(10)
```

You can slice it using statements such as

```
a[1]
a[2:4]
```

However, I want to do this based on a variable set elsewhere in the code. I can easily do this for the first one

```
i = 1
a[i]
```

But how do I do this for the other one? I've tried indexing with a list:

```
i = [2, 3, 4]
a[i]
```

But that doesn't work. I've also tried using a string:

```
i = "2:4"
a[i]
```

But that doesn't work either.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

that's what [`slice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) is for:

```
a = range(10)
s = slice(2,4)
print a[s]
```

That's the same as using `a[2:4]`.

Answer (score 14):

Why does it have to be a single variable? Just use two variables:

```
i, j = 2, 4
a[i:j]
```

If it *really* needs to be a single variable you could use a tuple.

Comment: My use case involved some detailed parsing of html, trying to find the last element in this html table. Code looked like `last_row = list(reversed(parsed_html_rows[-2:-1]))` 

In code review we realized i had a number of these 'magic ranges' in the code for plucking out various stuff. Giving a name to them makes it easier for me and the reviewer.. `last_row_indices = slice(-2, -1)` and `last_row = list(reversed(rows[last_row_indices])) # no more wtf'ing about why -2:-1`

Comment: 10 years late to the game but the tuple solution works like a charm. Context: working with multi-dimensional arrays/tensors in numpy/pytorch

Answer (score 3):

With the assignments below you are still using the same type of slicing operations you show, but now with variables for the values.

```
a = range(10)
i = 2
j = 4
```

then

```
print a[i:j]
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a=range(10)
>>> i=[2,3,4]

>>> a[i[0]:i[-1]]
range(2, 4)

>>> list(a[i[0]:i[-1]])
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this recently, while looking up how to have the user mimic the usual slice syntax of `a:b:c`, `::c`, etc. via arguments passed on the command line.

The argument is read as a string, and I'd rather not split on `':'`, pass that to `slice()`, etc. Besides, if the user passes a *single* integer `i`, the intended meaning is clearly `a[i]`. Nevertheless, `slice(i)` will default to `slice(None,i,None)`, which isn't the desired result.

In any case, the most straightforward solution I could come up with was to read in the string as a variable `st` say, and then recover the desired list slice as `eval(f"a[{st}]")`.

This uses the [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) builtin and an [f-string](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/) where `st` is interpolated inside the braces. It handles precisely the usual colon-separated slicing syntax, since it just plugs in that colon-containing string as-is.