# In Python, is there a way to save an index subset of an array to use again later?

Tags: python, arrays

My code currently has an array, lets say for example:

```
arr = np.ones((512, 512)).
```

There is an area of the array that interests me. I usually access it like this:

```
arr[50:200,150:350] #do stuff here.
```

I was wondering, is there some way to make a variable that holds `[50:200,150:350]`? This way, if I need to slightly change my mask, I can do it once, on the top of the file, instead of everywhere it is accessed.

I tried `mask = [50:200,150:350]`, `arr[mask]` but Python syntax won't allow that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501806/what-does-the-slice-function-do-in-python

Comment: Good question, Python native list and tuples can be sliced with `slice()` https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#slice but numpy has a richer interface.

Comment: I think this is what you might be looking for: [Slicing a list using a variable, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10573523/2314737).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a slice object for Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917173/how-can-i-create-a-slice-object-for-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `numpy` extends slicing and allows multiple `slice()` objects, one per dimension.

```py
import numpy
o = numpy.ones((32, 32))
print(o[3:5,3:5])

foo = slice(3,5), slice(3,5)
print(o[foo])
```

Both incantations produce same result :)